# New Tag Request: html5builder

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

Embarcadero Technologies released a new version of RadPHP with a new name, **HTML5 Builder**. But there is currently no tag in StackOverflow for the new product name.

Users are probably going to workaround the issue by combining existing tags, which might leave to things like:

- **[Embarcadero HTML5 Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271685/embarcadero-html-5-builder)**: *html5*, *builder*, *embarcadero*.

I think it would be better to provide a tag *html5builder* for questions regarding this product, questions that might have nothing to do, for example, with HTML5.

Comment: Why on earth would questions that have nothing to do with html5 be tagged with `html5builder`?

Comment: @Lix Why on earth would questions that have nothing to do with C++ be tagged with [tag:c++builder]?

Comment: @yan - I didn't notice the spelling mistake in the link... I thought you were making up tag names... x_x

Comment: @Lix Yeah, I ninja edited that ;)

Comment: HTML5 Builder is an IDE, so questions about the interface will, for example, have nothing to do with the HTML5 programming language. Same goes for questions about PHP, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery and other technologies you can use with HTML5 Builder.

Comment: @Gallaecio Could you please unaccept my answer? I'm agreeing with you that the tag is appropriate, and giving a few more details about why that is, but I don't have 1500 rep on Stack Overflow, thus can't create the tag and can't resolve the issue you bring up. Keep the "accepted mark" for whoever comes along and actually creates the tag ;)

Comment: I don't really like the fact that a tag would be created with an ambiguous meaning. If my latest PHP project was called iOS7, I think people would raise some eyebrows when I create that tag...

Comment: @Lix Well the IDE is not call HTML5, I think [html5builder] is not really that ambiguous. I wouldn't mind if we adopted a "company-product" policy for tags, something like [embarcadero-html5builder], but that would lead to some very long tags...

Comment: Perhaps [tag:html5builder-ide] would be more appropriate...

Comment: @Lix That could work as well... But I still don't think that [html5builder] is ambiguous, if you want ambiguous, how about we talk [tag:crap]? (spoiler: Change Risk Analysis and Predictions)

Comment: I guess my "complaint" should be directed at the people who chose the name...

Comment: Did somebody just call HTML5 a programming language?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Well if you evil mods didn't close questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145176/is-html-considered-a-programming-language), perhaps people wouldn't be making such mistakes... ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that we have tags for:

- [C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++builder),
- [JBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbuilder),

...and almost every other development tool known to man, I think [html5builder] would be appropriate.

Since there's already [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271685/embarcadero-html-5-builder) that could use the tag, could someone with 1500 rep create it please? The question is horribly mistagged, and *probably* will be closed as Not a Real Question if the OP doesn't clear it up a bit, but right now it's there, open, and about HTML5 Builder.

Also please note that [HTML5 Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/HTML5-Builder) is the name Embarcadero chose for the product, it's not a 
name for a specific version of the product.

**Update**

kiamlaluno [went ahead and created the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12271685/revisions). Feel free to use it if you find other questions about HTML5 Builder, and please remove any pointless tags they might have.