# New Tag Request: rpcl

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

RadPHP XE, RadPHP XE2 and HTML5 Builder both are based on an open source PHP library: the **RPCL**. But there is currently no tag in StackOverflow for this library.

As a result, questions that have little to do with *HTML5 Builder* or *RadPHP*, but are actually about the library itself, can only tbe tagged with the product tag — just like tagging Zend Framework questions with *zend-studio* instead of *zend-framework*.

I would like the **rpcl** tag to be provided so questions about the RPCL library can be properly tagged, and followed by users that do not necessarily use the same IDE.

**Update**

As requested, these are some questions that could benefit from this tag:

- **[Will Embarcadero RadPHP XE2 scale to an e-commerce site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030852/will-embarcadero-radphp-xe2-scale-to-an-e-commerce-site)** (*it includes several questions, some have more to do with the library than with the product*)
- **[delphi for php form in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994038/delphi-for-php-form-in-center)** (*the question, or rather the answer, has nothing to do with the IDE*)
- **[How can I get the results to be paged like almost all web pages do in radphp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913811/how-can-i-get-the-results-to-be-paged-like-almost-all-web-pages-do-in-radphp)**

Basically, half the questions asked about *[RadPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radphp)* or *HTML5 Builder* have actually more to do with the underlying library, the *RPCL*.

Comment: We don't create tags unless there are questions that could use them, please point us to some example questions you think would benefit from the tag, similarly to how you did in your [earlier request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148112/new-tag-request-html5builder).

Answer (score 2):

**[Added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3994038/revisions)** by [kiamlaluno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno).